# how to customer add multiple comments for a product IN PRESTASHOP

Tags: prestashop

I am using productcomments module for comments. In this only one comment can added at a time.No add comment link for further.I have set

Minimum time between 2 comments from the same user - 15 seconds

but after 15 seconds no add comments link or button not showing.if i login through other user also cant show any add comment link.For all products i can add only one comments,i cant add second comment,what is issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This bug has already been fixed in the last release:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/faa975750dcc222069e6b5b2703ab767923aedd0